# dun goofed the files in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

Tags: libraries

there was some weird package issue with (in my limited understanding) 32/64 bit libraries, so i went around making symlinks to the file my lamp installation expected to the ones that actually existed. i did this for a # of files in here:

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

however php still ended up not working (separate issue) and now i believe i have a screwed up lib directory. is there a way to revert those library files?